# Roll through shown subsections in the headline navigation so that there is only a fixed number visible at all times

Tags: beamer, headline

I would like to have only three sections and three subsections shown at all time in the headline.

For the sections I have a code (not mine) that works, however it doesn't work for the subsections and I don't understand the language enough to solve it on my own..

For the section it is working with the following code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\geometry{paperwidth=192mm,paperheight=108mm}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}  
}

\makeatletter
       \newcount\c@p
       \newcount\c@m

\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
    \hbox to #1{%
        \vbox{
        {
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
            \vskip0.5625ex%
            \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
            \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
                \ifnum##5=\c@part%
                    \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
                    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
                    \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
                    \c@p=\c@section%
                    \c@m=\c@section%
                    \advance\c@m by -1 %
                    \advance\c@p by 1 %
                    \ifnum\c@section=##1%
                        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                        \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                        {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
                    \else%
                        \ifnum##1=\c@m%
                            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                            \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                            {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}
                            %
                        \else%
                            \ifnum##1=\c@p%
                                \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                                \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                                {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
                                %
                            \else%
                                %
                            \fi%
                        \fi%
                        %
                    \fi%
                    %
                    \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex%
                    \dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
                    \box\beamer@tempbox%
                \fi%
                }%
            \dohead\vskip0.5625ex%
            }
        }
        \hfil%
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \@tempdimb=3em%
    \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
        \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
            \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}


\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Sub 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Sub 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Sub 4}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Sub 5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}

\end{document}
```

Keeps 3 sections and rolls when going to the 4th.
[image]
[image]

Keeps 3 subsections but only show those 3 even when going on the 4th.
[image]
[image]